# How do i get GCInfo in java 8?

Tags: memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'd like to write a command that would print all the information about the last GC (start time, finish time, free memory after the gc etc.) and i found a lot of examples for java 7 which don't work for java 8.
I don't necessarily need a listener i just want that when the command is used it'll give me all the info from the last gc.

Edit: I need this for a minecraft server where every admin can type let's say /gcinfo and it would send them a nice formatted message like:

max memory: w

free memory: x

memory after gc: y

memory before gc: z

time since last gc: × seconds

Comment: why don't you enable GC logging? it does exactly that

Comment: I dont need logging, i only need the data when someone performs the command.
I edited the description.

Comment: I guess this can be done with MXBean, at least I would start from there